# Exercise 6.5 Knuth's TeXbook

Tags: tex-core, texbook.tex

Running this exercise according to the suggestions on its answer in Appendix B, I got the following result :

[image]

The following lines can be seen in the log:

`Loose \hbox <badness 4>` ...       Corresponding to the line *Once upon a time*

`Underfull \hbox <badness 230>` ... Corresponding to the line *in a distant galaxy*

`Loose \hbox <badness 15>`...       Corresponding to the line *called Ööç, there lived*

`Loose \hbox <badness 0>` ...       Corresponding to the line *a computer named R. J.*

Q1) What is the difference between a `Loose` box and an `Underfull` box ?

Q2) The 4th message above has `badness = 0`. So, why the warning ?

Comment: For an explanation of "overfull" vs. "loose" hboxes, refer to page 302 (last single "dangerous bend" of that page) of the TeXbook.

Comment: `\hbadness=-1` and 0>-1, so the line is reported since it's loose. The two final lines of the paragraphs are not reported as they are "decent" because of the infinite glue in them.

Comment: Could you add the code you ran as well. Not everyone has the TeXBook at hand.

Answer (score 10):

TeX assigns badness to the boxes it builds with a rule that depends on the amount of glue stretching or shrinking. The rule can be found in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic.

If a box has badness b<13 it's classified *decent*; if 13 ≤ b < 100 the box is *tight* if glue had to shrink or *loose* if glue had to stretch. If 100 ≤ b < 10000 the box is *very loose* (this case can't happen with shrinking). The badness can never exceed 10000, in that case the box is *underfull*. The box can also be *overfull*, when TeX is not able to shrink the glue to fit the text in the available space; the badness is again 10000.

TeX reports boxes when their badness exceeds a threshold whose value is in the internal parameters `\hbadness` (for horizontal boxes) and `\vbadness` (for vertical boxes). In this report the terms *tight*, *loose*, *underfull* and *overfull* are used in a slightly different sense than before (the former meaning is important when demerits are assessed for typesetting a paragraph):

- *loose* means positive badness but less than 10000, glue had to stretch
- *tight* means positive badness but less than 10000, glue had to shrink
- *underfull* means badness 10000, glue had to stretch
- *overfull* means badness 10000, glue had to shrink

In the example, `\hbadness` has been set to -1, so TeX reports all boxes that are not decent (the badness can never be negative). The final lines of the paragraphs are not reported because the infinite glue in them (from \parfillskip) makes them always decent. Some of them is loose even if the badness is computed as 0 (the badness is computed as non zero and then truncated).

This can be seen with the following example:

```
\hbadness=-1
\hbox spread 1sp{a b}
\hbox spread -1sp{a b}
```

causes the following report

```
Loose \hbox (badness 0) detected at line 2
\tenrm a b

Tight \hbox (badness 0) detected at line 3
\tenrm a b
```

Yes, TeX is very fussy, sometimes.