# Using TikZ to celebrate Valentine's Day

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

While this is not a specific inquiry, I would like to witness the creativity of the members on this forum.

As it is the 14th of February, I had hoped to commemorate the occasion by creating an aesthetically pleasing image that conveys love (even though I'm single af XD). With that being said, I present to you a simple mandala I was able to produce using TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}    
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\definecolor{vblue}{HTML}{041562}
\definecolor{vred}{HTML}{DA1212}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings, shadings, fadings}    
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\shade[inner color = vblue, outer color=vred] (0,0)circle(4.5);
\draw[vblue, line width=0.7mm] (0,0)circle(4.5);

%You can think of a for loop here and draw these things once !
\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (45:3.5)..controls(60:4) and (65:3)..(80:3.5);
\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (10:3.5)..controls(25:3) and (30:4)..(45:3.5);

\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (135:3.5)..controls(120:4) and (115:3).. (100:3.5);
\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (170:3.5)..controls(155:3)and(150:4)..(135:3.5);

\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (-45:3.5)..controls(-60:4) and (-65:3)..(-80:3.5);
\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (-10:3.5)..controls(-25:3) and (-30:4)..(-45:3.5);

\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (-135:3.5)..controls(-120:4) and (-115:3).. (-100:3.5);
\draw[line width=0.4mm, vblue] (-170:3.5)..controls(-155:3)and(-150:4)..(-135:3.5);

%The hearts 
\foreach\i in{45, 135, -45, -135}{
\node[vblue, rotate=-90+\i] at (\i:4) {\faHeart};
\node[vblue, rotate=90+\i] at (\i:3) {\faHeart};
\node[vblue, rotate=-90+\i+35] at (\i+35:3.5) {\faHeart};
\node[vblue, rotate=-90+\i-35] at (\i-35:3.5) {\faHeart};
\node[vred, scale=0.5, rotate=-90+\i+35] at (\i+35:3.5) {\faHeart};
\node[vred, scale=0.5, rotate=-90+\i-35] at (\i-35:3.5) {\faHeart};
}
%The curvy lines and the I love you text
\foreach\i in{0,90,180,270}{
\draw[vblue, line width=0.5mm] (\i:2.5) ..controls(\i+5:2.75) and (\i-5:3.25)..(\i:3.75);
\fill[vblue] (\i:3.75)circle(0.05);
\begin{scope}[shift={(\i:3.75)}]
\draw[vblue,line width=0.5mm, rotate=\i+90] (0,0)..controls(0.25,-0.25)and(0.75,0.25)..(1,0);
\draw[vblue,line width=0.5mm, rotate=\i+90] (0,0)..controls(-0.25,-0.25)and(-0.75,0.25)..(-1,0);
\end{scope}
\node[rotate=\i-90, vblue] at (\i:4.1) {\calligra I love you};
}

%The inner layer
\shade[inner color = vred, outer color=vblue!98] (0,0)circle(2.5);
\draw[vred, line width=0.7mm] (0,0)circle(2.5);

\foreach\i in{36, 72,108, ...,360}{
%The petals
\draw[vred, fill=vblue] (\i:0.2)to[bend right=30](\i:0.75)to[bend right=30](\i:0.2);

%The inside blue heart
\node[rotate=\i-90, vblue, scale=0.95] at (\i:1.25) {\faHeart};

%The outer layer of the heart 
\node[rotate=\i-90, vred] at (\i:1.25) {\faHeart[regular]};
%The lines and their decorations
\draw[line width=0.1mm, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with{\node[scale=0.25, vred, rotate=\i-90-18] {\faHeart}; }}}, vblue] (\i+18:0.25)..controls (\i+10:1.25) and (\i+18+10:1.75) ..(\i+18:2);

\draw[vred, line width=0.1mm] (\i:1.5)..controls (\i-5:1.7) and (\i+5:1.8)..(\i:2);  

\draw[thick, vred, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .75 with{ \fill[vblue] circle[radius=0.025]; }}} ] (\i:0.75)--(\i:1);
}
%The Kernel 
\draw[vred, fill=vblue] (0,0)circle(0.25);
\node[vred, scale=0.75] at (-0.01,0) {\faHeart};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

That's cool, isn't it? So, if you were in a relationship, what creative surprises have you prepared for your partner? Alternatively, if you're in the same situation as me and just looking to kill boredom, what have you been up to? XD

Comment: Just posted in chat: https://twitter.com/overleaf/status/1625482517976326147?t=gG94XzAvUgjLrbGkuFufHg&s=19

Comment: @CarLaTeX Such a classic !

Comment: We've done this before... https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139733/15036

Comment: Not in `tikz`, but see the end of my answer using acrostics: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121440/tex-assistance-in-writing-hidden-acrostics/121942#121942. She hasn't left me yet, LOL.

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately not the right place to put it, and pretty much oppinion related ... unless you have a concrete question related to your code ...

Comment: @MS-SPO It is a good place to do so, I've seen a lot of posts inviting people to show their creativity or show what they've produced using `Asymptote`, `pstricks`, `tikz`... see the `fun` tag